# why after deploying mvc app to azure tables not created?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I use code first and the app works well on a local database which was generated.

But when I deploy to Azure, although it succeeds, the tables are not created, just the empty database.

I excluded the local `app_data` folder and chose to run code first migrations
in the deployment options.

Any tips what's wrong?

Comment: What does your database connection string look like, and how is the one deployed to Azure different to the one locally?  Are you using an SQL Azure database, or trying to use `localdb`?  I don't think `localdb` works on Azure (or it didn't used to)/

Comment: yes, I want to create database on azure, not use local and somehow is not creating there during publishing. Local webconfig is like this: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-Installations.Web-20150328120622.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-Installations.Web-20150328120622;Integrated Security=True"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>   but how can I see what connection string is on Azure?

Comment: go on your web app --> configure --> and scroll down until you find connection strings.
If there is any connection string configured here with the same name, it will overwrite the one you pass on the web.config file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you configured Azure deployment to replace connection strings (via the publishing wizard) or are you using environmental variables in your code? It doesn't sound like it. It sounds like you deployed with localdb which does not work in Azure.

You need to either (there are more options, but these are easy to implement):

1. Configure your deployment process to update your web.config with your SQL Azure connection string (you can use config transformations or deplyment wizard)
2. Use Azure environmental variables to be used automatically when running in Azure and local variables when locally

Comment: well, I checked box "use the connection string at runtime (update dest web.config)  something else should I do?

Comment: is Seed method necessary do populate?

Comment: @motif you would need to populate the box with the actual Azure SQL connection string and it overwrite it with this value when you deploy